# SharePoint Online Web Part Query

Tags: sharepoint-online, search, content-query-web-part, kql, search-query

I'm trying to add [AccountName] "does not contain TEST".  Below is the existing code. Can some one show me how to add AccountName does not contain the word 'Test'?

```
{searchboxquery} contentclass=*  -AccountName:laitramllc.onmicrosoft.com -WorkEmail:Laitramllc.onmicrosoft.com -WorkEmail:5135.RandDTestingArea@laitram.com Department<>NLWC AND Department<>N/A NOT(AccountName:USNO* OR AccountName:USDL* OR AccountName:EUAM* OR AccountName:SABR* OR AccountName:USBA* OR AccountName:AUML* OR AccountName:CNSH* OR AccountName:CNWG* OR AccountName:USHA* OR AccountName:USGR* OR AccountName:CNCD* OR AccountName:USDS* OR AccountName:USHN* OR AccountName:EUWE* OR AccountName:USSP*)
```

Comment: Try adding this at the end of query: `AND NOT(AccountName:Test)`. Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: This worked! Thank you!

Comment: Great, glad it worked for you!

Comment: I have added it as an answer below. Please [Upvote(^)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) & [accept as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) as it helped you & it will help others with similar question in future.

Comment: Hi Travis, can you please accept below response as an answer as it worked for you?

Answer (score 1):

Add this at the end of query: `AND NOT(AccountName:Test)`

Your query will be like:

```
{searchboxquery} contentclass=*  -AccountName:laitramllc.onmicrosoft.com -WorkEmail:Laitramllc.onmicrosoft.com -WorkEmail:5135.RandDTestingArea@laitram.com Department<>NLWC AND Department<>N/A NOT(AccountName:USNO* OR AccountName:USDL* OR AccountName:EUAM* OR AccountName:SABR* OR AccountName:USBA* OR AccountName:AUML* OR AccountName:CNSH* OR AccountName:CNWG* OR AccountName:USHA* OR AccountName:USGR* OR AccountName:CNCD* OR AccountName:USDS* OR AccountName:USHN* OR AccountName:EUWE* OR AccountName:USSP*) AND NOT(AccountName:Test)
```